# Merge the awk script in ksh script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have an awk script file1.awk to read the 2nd line after the pattern "-----------" present in my input.txt file, the content of the script is given below::

```
BEGIN { RS = "------------------------------------------------------------------------" ; FS = "\n" }

{
        print $2
}
```

I am calling the awk script from my shell script file2.ksh in the below format.

```
gawk -f file1.awk input.txt > output.txt
```

Can someone suggest me a way to merge the functionality of file1.awk in file2.ksh, so that i dont have 2 scipts.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding shebang to your awk script

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN { RS = "------------------------------------------------------------------------" ; FS = "\n" }

{
        print $2
}
```

And then

```
file1.awk input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Can i do  this ??

awk 'BEGIN { RS = "------------------------------------------------------------------------" ; FS = "\n" }{print $2}' input.txt > output.txt

Comment: Shebang should work, did you grant exec permissions to awk script? Your one line bash script above should work too

Comment: Don't use shebangs to execute awk scripts as they remove functionality compared to simply calling awk.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
gawk -f file1.awk input.txt > output.txt
```

with:

```
gawk '
BEGIN { RS = "------------------------------------------------------------------------" ; FS = "\n" }

{
        print $2
}
' input.txt > output.txt
```